# Windows + Canopy + Ipython Notebook + Python 3 + Python "tweepy" package

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, jupyter, canopy

Hey Guys I am using Windows 7, and started learning Pyton (great language). And for my online tutorial exercise i have to use above combination.

- I have installed canopy which came with ipython notebook.
- But Ipython notebook just have kernel (python 2) no python 3. But i have to use python 3 for exercises.
- And please guide me how to install tweepy library of python to download tweets in Canopy. (I mean any commands or options).

Answer (score 1):

Whoever provided you with that requirement list was incorrect. There is no released version of Canopy which supports Python 3. I suggest that you install Python 3 using conda.